# sql statement to return based on what is the last row based on a where clause

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two table as below

**match**

```
id (PK)
match_id
name
birthdate
bio
```

**message_long**

```
id (PK)
message
from_id
to_id
match_id (FK to match_on on match table)
unix_timestamp
```

[image]

[image]

These two tables are responsible for storing chat conversation logs. I can retreive a conversation by the following sql query

```
select * from message_log where match_id = '2434';
```

I would like to come up with an sql query that would return the match_ids of conversations only if:

- The last message (last message received) in the conversation (match_id) is not from '765' (from_id column)

Can someone please help me construct this sql query?

Comment: We very much prefer *text* to screenshots. Text can be copy/pasted. Plus, as always: your version of Postgres?

Comment: I agree with Erwin. Ideally table definitions should be posted as `create table` statements. That way it's easy to setup a test environment.

Answer (score 0):

> The last message (last message received) in the conversation
>   (match_id) [which] is not from '765' (from_id column)

Seems like a straight forward query:

```
SELECT *
FROM   message_log
WHERE  match_id = '2434'
AND    from_id <> '765'
ORDER  BY unix_timestamp DESC NULLS LAST
LIMIT  1;
```

If `unix_timestamp` can be NULL, you need to add `NULLS LAST` to `DESC` sort order:

- [PostgreSQL sort by datetime asc, null first?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9510509/postgresql-sort-by-datetime-asc-null-first/9511492#9511492)

If, on the other hand, you mean to return all match_id's of a conversation only if the the last message is not from '765', then:

```
SELECT *
FROM   message_log
WHERE  match_id = '2434'
AND (
   SELECT from_id
   FROM   message_log
   WHERE  match_id = '2434'
   ORDER  BY unix_timestamp DESC NULLS LAST
   LIMIT  1
   ) <> '765';
```

An index on `(match_id, unix_timestamp)` or even `(match_id, unix_timestamp, from_id)` would help query performance a lot.

Aside: Data type `varchar(500)` for all your IDs is rather odd. Are you sure these shouldn't be just `integer` (or `bigint`)?

Comment: I think you have missed `return the match_ids of conversations only if`. OP wants to return the result only if `The last message (last message received) in the conversation (match_id) [which] is not from '765' (from_id column)`

Comment: I am not sure though.. thats what I understood

Comment: @NandakumarV: Hmm, you may be right. I added a query for the second interpretation.

Comment: What i understood was entirely different, I have created the query from what i understood, http://stackoverflow.com/a/30883911/1418007

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I have understood the question correctly. As I understood you need,

> All match ids whose last converstion is not been originated from 765.

If we consider a sample data

```
matchid fromid  toid    messagetime
2334    600     765     2015-06-17 11:30:36
2334    765     600     2015-06-17 11:30:43
2334    600     765     2015-06-17 11:30:52
2335    600     765     2015-06-17 11:37:44
2335    765     600     2015-06-17 11:37:56
2335    600     765     2015-06-17 11:38:06
2335    765     600     2015-06-17 11:48:03
```

you want the match id **2334**. match id **2335** should be omitted since the last conversation is from **765**.

If this is what you need this query will get the result

```
SELECT resultmatchids FROM 
(
    SELECT 
    DISTINCT ON (match_id) match_id,
    (CASE WHEN from_id != 765 THEN match_id ELSE NULL END) AS resultmatchids
    FROM match 
    ORDER BY match_id, unix_timestamp DESC
) AS recentmatch
WHERE recentmatch.resultmatchids IS NOT NULL
```